# Azure pipelines, how to use a Dockerfile from an other repository?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to build a Azure DevOps pipeline that uses a separate repository for Dockerfiles / templates. Whats the cleanest way to use Dockerfiles from another repository?

We have experimented with having the template refer to the dockerfile but the build server seems to not have access to the filepath.

In Dockerfile repository:

```
steps: 
- script: docker build -f pathTo/Dockerfile
```

In build repository:

```
steps: 
- template: Dockerfilerepository.yml
```

We want this to create a docker build process in side the building repository but we instead get this error message:

```
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/vsts/work/1/s/pipelines: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

you'd need to checkout that repo separately and then you can use files in that repo, you can use a script step for that, something like this:

```
git clone https://x-access-token:$(github-access-token)@github.com/ORG/OTHER_PRIVATE_REPO.git
```

but its probably not the best idea to keep docker files in a separate repo